# Regular Expression to find a value in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I've got a bunch of strings that look like this:

- This is string 1 [id:10]
- This is string 2 [id:4]
- This is string 3 [id:77]

Using javascript, how can I get an array of 10,4,77? These will be values of input fields all with the class form-text so I have the option of iterating of them.

Thanks,
Howie

Comment: Have you tried any solution?

Comment: Are you looking for a single regular expression that would return an array? A regular expression might not be the right tool for the job. Why do you want to use a regex?

Comment: How about a find all like function with this `/\[id:(\d+)\]/` Where captures are turned into an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you have the given strings in array. Then using `Array.map` you can retrieve the id's

```
var a = ["This is string 1 [id:10]", "This is string 2 [id:4]", "This is string 3 [id:77]"];

var result = a.map(function (item) {
    return /.*?\[id:([\d]{1,})\]/g.exec(item)[1];
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\d+(?=\])
```

Try this.See demo .

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/18

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var test = "[id:10]";
var result = test.split(":")[1].split("]")[0];
//result should have 10
```